# JBoss AS 6: DeploymentScanner not showing in JMX console

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, jboss6.x, mbeans

I work in a project with several, totally separated, instances of JBoss AS (6.1.0.Final). I need to access the MBean **org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner**, but it is missing for one of these servers. More precisely, the *jboss.deployment* domain doesn't show up at all.

I have diffed the conf directories of the servers without finding any relevant differences between the instances. I have also searched after *DeploymentScanner* in the conf directory of a server for which the MBean appears, but got no hit.

How come the **DeploymentScanner** is missing for one of my server instances? Or in other words, where and how do I configure this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

most probably the deployment scanner extension on this JBoss instance is not enabled. Have a look in the server configuration for

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
```

**edit** @Magnilex: You're right, the above is for JBoss 7.0. (step once again in the numbering trap between EAP and OS version)
For JBoss 6.1.0 (OS) the setting of the DeploymentScanner is in "hdscanner-jboss-beans.xml". So you chould check your configuration for a "setting in the namespace 'urn:jboss:bean-deployer'".
Could not point it in more detail as I have no JBoss 6.1.0 (OS) installed. I had only a quick view in the installation package. But I guess you should now be able to find the related setting.